# Synchronise classList.toggle and innerHTML change with Javscript button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I search to toggle a button with two messages with `innerHTML`, and the css class with bootstrap 4 and `classList.toggle`.

Read more would be show on a blue button with a circle up icon and class btn btn-primary, and Read Less with a green button with a circle down icon and class btn btn-success.

**Fontawesome** is used for the icons.

I need to work with class css, because I use bootstrap for each button.

When I use this code, the result bean not synchrone after three clicks on the button.

Thanks for you for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <style>
        #more {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
        imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span
            id="dots"
            >...</span
        ><span id="more"
            >erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec
            congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut
            aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac.
            In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae
            dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non
            fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span
        >
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">
        Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i>
    </button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
            var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
            var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
            var switchCss = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            if (dots.style.display === "none") {
                dots.style.display = "inline";
                btnText.innerHTML = "Read more <i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up'></i>";
                switchCss.classList.toggle("btn-primary");
                moreText.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                dots.style.display = "none";
                btnText.innerHTML = "Read less <i class='   fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down'></i>";
                switchCss.classList.toggle("btn-success");
                moreText.style.display = "inline";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what do you want to achieve, you do not tell in your question?

Comment: @Evren Thanks for this precision, I forgot this in the first version of this message.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this modification it will work for color problem but other solution would be cancelling your previous class name and adding new one in button, it probably overwrites after third click

```
 if (dots.style.display === "none") {
                    dots.style.display = "inline";
                    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more <i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up'></i>";
                    switchCss.style.background="blue";
                    moreText.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    dots.style.display = "none";
                    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less <i class='   fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down'></i>";
                    switchCss.style.background="green";
                    moreText.style.display = "inline";
                }
```

Comment: It's important to work with class, because i use bootstrap.